# Java - how can I stop an infinite while

Tags: java, android, while-loop

I'm new to Java and I'm making a Tetris game on Android Studio. I'm trying to do a "Pause/Start" button and it doesn't work. When I press the button PAUSE, the music and the game stops (it works as it should). But when I press Start again, the music continues but the game doesn't resume.

I've made a function "pause" with a `sleep()` inside a `while`, and a function "restart" with a boolean that becomes false (this sets the condition of the while)
Here is my code :

```
private void pause() {
    ps=true;
    while(ps) {
        try {
            sleep(4000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private void restart() {
    ps=false;
}
```

Here is a part of my `MainActivity`:

```
public void pauseButton (View view) {

    if (ps == false) {
        ps=true;
        GameState.getInstance().setUserAction(UserAction.PAUSE);
        mediaPlayer.pause();
    } else {
        ps=false;
        GameState.getInstance().setUserAction(UserAction.START);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
}
```

And here is what "Useraction.Pause/Start" is doing

```
case PAUSE:
    pause();
    break;
case START:
    restart();
    break;
```

how to make the function restart works ? I need to make the "while" stop or maybe a sleep stops in this function and I cannot.. Thanks for your help!

```
 public class GameThread extends Thread{


private Shape shape;

private Set<Block> remainingBlockSet = new HashSet<>();

private boolean isRunning = true;

private long time;

private char[] shapeTypes={'O', 'I', 'J', 'L', 'Z', 'S','T'};

private boolean ps = true;




 GameThread(){
    //La première pièce du jeu apparait
    spawnNewShape();
    //Initialisation du temps
    this.time = System.currentTimeMillis();

}


//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// METHODES DE GESTION DE LA THREAD
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


/**
 *Boucle événementielle
 */
@Override
public void run() {
    while (isRunning) {
        //On bouge la pièce en fonction des demande utilisateur (bouton préssé)
        processUserAction();

        //La pièce tombe
        processMoveDown();

        //On enlève les lignes remplie
        removeCompletedRows();

        //On effectue le rendu graphique
        RenderManager.getInstance().render(shape, remainingBlockSet);
    }
}







/**
 * Arret de la boucle événementielle
 */
 void stopRunning(){
    isRunning = false;
}


//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// METHODES DE GESTION DU JEU
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Traitement des actions utilisateur
 */
private void processUserAction()  {
    //On recupère la dernière action
    UserAction action = GameState.getInstance().getUserAction();
    switch (action) {
        case LEFT:
            moveLeft();
            break;
        case RIGHT:
            moveRight();
            break;
        case ROTATE:
            rotate();
            break;
        case FALL:
            fall();
            break;
        case PAUSE:
            pause();
            break;
        case RESUME:
            restart();
            break;


    }
    //On définit la dernière action à nulle
    GameState.getInstance().setUserAction(UserAction.NONE);

}




 // met en pause le jeu
  public void pause() {
   ps = true;
  while(ps) {
    try {
       sleep(5000);
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
 }
 }

 // permet de relancer le jeu
 public void restart() {
    ps=false;

}







private void fall(){
    while(shape.canMoveDown(remainingBlockSet)){
        shape.moveDown();
    }
}

private void rotate(){
    shape.rotate(remainingBlockSet);
}

/**
 * Décale la pièce d'une case vers la gauche
 */
private void moveLeft(){
    shape.moveLeft(remainingBlockSet);
}

/**
 * Décale la pièce d'une case vers la droite
 */
private void moveRight(){
    shape.moveRight(remainingBlockSet);
}



/**
 * Décale la pièce d'une case vers le bas
 */
private void processMoveDown(){
    //Si le laps de temps n'est pas écoulé on ne fait rien
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if(now-time < GameConstants.TIME_LAPS){
        return;
    }
    //Sinon la pièce descend

    if(shape.canMoveDown(remainingBlockSet)){
        shape.moveDown();
    }
    else{
        processShapeCollision();
    }

    //On redéfinit le temps comme le temps actuel
    time = System.currentTimeMillis();
}

private void processShapeCollision(){
    remainingBlockSet.addAll(shape.getBlockList());
    spawnNewShape();
}

   /**
    * A partir d'un caractère choisis aléatoirement, cette methode 
  permet 
 de générer la pièce qui
   * lui est associé.
    */
  private void spawnNewShape(){
    int x = (GameConstants.COLUMNS/2)-2;
    int y = 0;
    char shapeType = chooseRandomShape();
    switch (shapeType){
        case 'O':
            this.shape = new OShape(x,y);
            break;
        case 'T':
            this.shape = new TShape(x,y);
            break;
        case 'S':
            this.shape = new SShape(x,y);
            break;
        case 'I':
            this.shape = new IShape(x,y);
            break;
        case 'L':
            this.shape = new LShape(x,y);
            break;
        case 'Z':
            this.shape = new ZShape(x,y);
            break;
        case 'J':
            this.shape = new JShape(x,y);
            break;
        default:
            //imposible
            break;

    }
}


/**
 * Cette methode génère aléatoirement un entier entre 0 et 7. Ce dernier permet ensuite de
 * séléctioner le caractère de la pièce à faire appraitre.
 * @return un caractère correspondant à la prochaine pièce à faire apparaitre.
 */
private char chooseRandomShape(){
    int x = (int) (Math.random() * shapeTypes.length);
    return shapeTypes[x];
}






private void removeCompletedRows() {
    for(int y = GameConstants.ROWS-1; y>0; y--){
        List<Block> line = getBlockLine(y);
        if (isLineCompleted(line)){
            //Log.i(TAG,"la ligne"+y+"est pleine :"+line);
            removeLine(line);
            moveDownAboveBlocks(y);
        }
    }

}

private List<Block> getBlockLine(int y) {
    List<Block> line = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Block block : remainingBlockSet){
        if(y == block.getY()){
            line.add(block);
        }
    }
    return line;
}


private boolean isLineCompleted(List<Block> line) {
    for(int x = 0; x< GameConstants.COLUMNS; x++){
        boolean found = false;
        for(Block block : line){
            if (block.getX() == x){
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!found) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}


private void removeLine(List<Block> line){
    remainingBlockSet.removeAll(line);
}


private void moveDownAboveBlocks(int y){
    for(Block block : remainingBlockSet){
        if (block.getY()<y){
            block.moveDown();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: you have to call pause() or assign the ps = false inside the while loop to stop the while..

Comment: thanks for your answer. I tried it but it doesn't work :                       
            i don't know what condition to put in the "if"

Comment: At first glance, it looks as though what you have there would break your while loop the way that it is now.  I guess it depends on what else has been ceased before you went into your pause. Was anything else performed other than the call into pause that might need resuming? Or how are these triggered, such as touch up, touch down events for additional information would be helpful.

Comment: Are you sure it's a problem with the while loop? if you tried logging something for example inside the loop does it keep showing?

Comment: Can you list those dependencies in your question?  Perhaps someone will know of a current issue with one of them that will help you solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said it explicitly but I assume that UI works in a different thread, so you can press pause/restart button without being blocked by the running 'while' loop

Your code does not show either how you define `ps` variable - is it volatile? 
What we can see these code is NOT synchronized so does not put any memory barrier, in this case (when ps is not volatile) this variable might be 'cached' by the thread which runs the while loop and never re-read from memory again.

Please make sure that it is volatile - or AtomicBoolean, or put some synchronization in place (which would be good to have anyway here unless all operations in pausing/starting  are idempotent)

Please refer here for more details:
https://www.concretepage.com/java/thread-communication-using-volatile-in-java
https://jorosjavajams.wordpress.com/volatile-vs-synchronized/

Comment: Thanks for your answers ! Hum, ps is not volatile, I just made this : private boolean ps = false ; in the class where functions pause() and restart() are. So I'll try to make it as you said, volatile or AtomicBoolean. thanks!

Comment: Hello, I'm back again because I did not succeed .. I also tried to make a "notifyAll()" to stop the sleep loop in the restart function but it doesn't work

Comment: I added all my class in the first edit, maybe you'll see what happens

Comment: have you tried to debug & check what ` UserAction action = GameState.getInstance().getUserAction();` returns?
or add some logs to see which code is executed and which not?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably that you "Consume" the thread that you pause with which is almost certainly the GUI thread (Yes I said "the" gui thread because there is only one, as long as you have it, nothing else can happen on the GUI).  The second button can never be pushed because the first is still using the thread.

Any time you get any notification from the system, only take a very quick action and return the thread to the system immediately.  (The exception is the thread passed to "main" which you can keep forever)

the loop also won't do anything to pause your game unless you are doing the entire game on the gui thread. In other words if the game is on your main thread, locking up the gui thread won't stop it.

When they press the pause button, don't have the button call pause(), instead have it set ps=true and return.  Have your game loop (the thread that is actually running the game) check the ps flag every iteration and block as long as ps is true (The way you are doing it is fine, it just needs to be in other code).

Also ps should absolutely be volatile but that's never the problem...